# Secure login and security page check best practices with PHP

Tags: php, security, session, cookies, encryption

Would like to get some peoples views on the following:

- Is it good/best practice to query the database for every secure page on a website for a salted and encrypted code check between session / cookie and database value?

or

- Is it good/best practice to rely on salted and encrypted sessions and cookies (where both key and value are both salted and encrypted)?

So user id and access level are either picked up out of the database on every secure page or from the encrypted session / cookie value pair.

---

**CONCLUSION**

This is what I have chosen to do:

**LOGIN**

1. Validate username & md5(password) are in DB and are correct
2. Start a session
3. Session store encrypted key & value pairs for: user_id, admin, access_level
4. Create a ACCESS KEY by joining REMOTE IP & REMOTE USER AGENT & Config encription key, encrypt each, join the strings together and encrypt again
5. Store this value in both the db and session with the key encrypted
6. User is now logged in

**For page validation:**

I will choose two levels of page user access validation:

1. Low priority secure tasks eg details listings, upload an image, select queries mostly
2. High priority secure tasks eg delete & update

**Low priority page check:**

1. Simply check the existence of encrypted session keys and values for user_id, access_level & existence of access_key

**High priority page check:**

1. Query db for session access_key match and re-set session values for user_id, access_level

**Additional:**

I will add an IP recording feature which will track IPs in the DB for login attempts and if that login fails from that IP over 10 times, the IP gets banned.

Comment: Sessions and cookies are not the same thing! There's little use in encrypting session data and it's terribly insecure to store user credentials client-side. I don't think it's a question of good practices but of how web authentication works. You should never need to copy passwords around.

Comment: Log in once, trust your session data. Confirm password on changes to account/elevated security actions.

Comment: An IP-based check for login attempts is insufficient. Some botnets have boxes with hundreds of thousands of different IP's. Bans of a single IP are more likely to affect regular users and unlikely to shut out or even slow down some of the more resourceful attackers. You also need to implement an IP-independent restriction based on the account being guessed. Some attackers don't even *try* to guess from the same IP more than once. Guesses from many different IP's in a short time is often more suspicious than many from one IP. You need to monitor both and act accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not from cookies. The *session cookie* should be a completely meaningless pseudo-random blob of gobbledygook. This gobbledygook is the id of a session that is stored server side. This session data can be stored in a database or in the filesystem (which it is by default with PHP sessions). You authenticate the user once with his stored credentials, then you open a session for him and store his user id and whatever else you need in this session. The user is then identified and authenticated by his meaningless session cookie and the data which belongs to it. No more, no less.

There is an argument to be made for occasionally checking whether the data in the session is still in sync with the database though. Say, a user has certain "access levels" and you store this in the session when the user authenticates. Now you change the user's access level in the database; the session will still have an old copy of that data and the user will still be able to access levels he may not be allowed to anymore. It's up to you how often you want to verify this data against the canonical database store.

Answer (score 0):

You can place "sensitive" data in cookies, it is used by a lot of systems e.g. CodeIngnitter.

To minimize the risks make sure that your crypto is implemented correctly.

**IF** your crypto is ok then there is not much difference between a session cookie plus a db look-up and values stored in the cookie.

In both cases :

Use HTTPS if it is possible.

Use only HTTP_ONLY cookies, so the session cookie does not show up in document.cookie

Remove any "reflection" pages where you might display cookie information, a good example would be phpinfo() pages.

Be sure that you add some parts of the IP address to the mix, and maybe the User-Agent.

If somebody has managed to grab the cookie or session cookie it can't impersonate the user, unless it knows the User-Agent and can send HTTP request from that IP or IP Class.

Comment: Using cookies for sensitive info when databases and sessions are available is like buying a safe and keeping your expensive jewellery in a locked drawer.

Comment: Yes it is. But if we are talking about "logged_in" = 1 and "access_level" = 9 I think it is safe, and depending on the system it can save you a lot of SQL queries. Storing passwords (hashed/salted or not) it is not a good idea.

Comment: @DuppyWeb *Especially* with "access_level=9" you do *not* give this information to the client. That enables anyone with the necessary skill to upgrade his access level anytime.

Comment: @deceze Yeah, if somebody has the skill to break a correctly implemented AES then you are out of luck.

Comment: @DuppyWeb It's possible that you leak your encryption key in some way (\*cough\*heartbleed\*cough\*), which means an attacker would not need to *break* anything but simply encrypt whatever he wants in the same way that you'd do. There are simply so many possibilities this *could* potentially fail, while keeping all data server side in a session has much fewer chances of failing.